# Meaning of "profumi alla spina"

Tags: meaning

I know that "birra alla spina" means "draught beer" (beer served from cask/keg), but I have recently heard the term "profumi alla spina" and I was not able to find out exactly what it means. Are they provided to the client directly from a tap, as draught beer?

Comment: There is some of a trend of calling _alla spina_ goods that are simply sold loose, by measure (one of the most usual is _detersivi_, washing liquids). You can find more such by googling «"alla spina" -birra»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extract is from a popular feminine website. The idea is that you can refill the same perfume bottle once it is empty. There is also an “ecological concept” at play in this case:

> ***[I profumi alla spina](https://www.donnaglamour.it/che-cosa-sono-profumi-alla-spina/guide/?refresh_ce)*** si definiscono anche profumi equivalenti, in quanto sono molto simili alle fragranze prodotte dalle grandi marche. La differenza? Certamente risiede nel prezzo, molto più accessibile, ma i vantaggi non finiscono qui. Infatti non è assolutamente da trascurare l’aspetto ecosostenibile di questi prodotti, i quali ***sono venduti con dei flaconcini che possono essere di volta in volta riutilizzati***: appena il profumo sarà esaurito potrete facilmente ricaricare il contenitore in negozio.

[image]

(www.donnaglamour.it)